# Save not successful for big cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, save

I am working with Matlab 2009b in Windows 7 64 bit environment.

I am not able to save cell array of size 2.5GB using v7.3 switch but save is successful for struct of arrays of size 6 GB, containing only double values. Please advise me about the alternatives I can try.

**What is working**

I am able to save following variable in workspace successfully.

```
>> whos
  Name             Size                  Bytes  Class     Attributes

  master_data      1x159            6296489360  struct              

>> save('arrayOfStruct.mat','-v7.3')
```

Here master data is an array of 159 structure. Each of these 159 structures have five array of 1 million double values. Mat file of 594 MB saved in the filesystem.

**What is not working**

I am not able to save a cell array, which contains strings, doubles and array of doubles.

```
>> whos
  Name                     Size                  Bytes  Class    Attributes

  result_combined      57888x100            2544467328  cell               

>> save('cellArray.mat','-v7.3');
```

When I execute the save command, a cellArray.mat file of size 530 MB is generated in the filesystem but the prompt never returns to matlab.(I have waited for more than 4 hours and run this after restarting the computer). If I terminate the matlab program while it is waiting for the prompt to return, the generated cellArray.mat is not usable as matlab shows the file cannot be loaded as it is corrupt.

Please suggest what I can try to save this variable result_combined.

**NOTE**
The save command works successfully in Matlab 2015a. Any suggestions as to how I can make it work in Matlab 2009b. I am using Matlab 2009b as default and do not want to migrate to 2015a as it might break existing setup.

Comment: Is disabling 7.3 switch an option?

Comment: No. Variable size is more than 2 GB.

Comment: Apparently it's a bug in 2009b. I don't have it to test out, but one way to approach this might be by using `matfile` function. Try saving an empty matrix, then open the file using matfile in writable mode (see help) and then adding your cell to that file

Comment: matfile command is not present in 2009b version. it was introduced from 2011b (http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html). Please provide any other suggestion.

Comment: You are right, since mat file is in fact and HDF file I would try to use `hdf5write`. You will have to write custom reading and writing routines, however. In this case it also does not make much sense to stick to matlab conventions for mat files, and just use something quick and dirty with vanilla HDF.